# Superuser Access denied on admin menu cache clear

Tags: 7, users

Just took over dev work on this D7 site, so I don't know exactly how everything is set up. When I try to clear the cache via admin menu, I get an access denied message on `/admin_menu/flush-cache?token=tokenvalue`.

It seems that when I got to clear all caches at `/admin/config/development/performance`, it silently fails some of the time, and in some times I'll get the success message.

Any suggestions on where to start diagnosing this? I don't see anything in the drupal or server logs relating to this aside from the access denied message.

Comment: Check for all permissions of user(which you are using to clear cache), whether user having appropriate permissions to do that.
If it didn't works well check in clean drupal installation and compare both permissions

Comment: If you are using user 1, you should not be beholden to any permission checks, unless there is custom code that is blocking you for whatever reason.

Comment: Any idea on how to identify said possible custom code? Could it possibly be a database error of some kind? The database definitely has this particular account as uid 1, so there's something off somewhere.

Comment: Add devel module and add look to the permissions with block DNA. Also look if you have all bypass permissions as admin. Is drush cc all working? Check directory permissions, look if they are writeable to build up the new css again. Check aggregation. Check temp folder under media..